# php-fpm nginx time-out error

Tags: php, symfony, docker, nginx

I have a problem, that I've been struggling with for a few days.

I have a symfony2 project set up with docker-compose, using php-fpm and nginx. Suddenly my local machine starts timing out when I access a specific page of my project.

This is the php-fpm log:

```
[09-Aug-2017 05:05:27] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
[09-Aug-2017 05:05:27] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[09-Aug-2017 05:05:51] WARNING: [pool www] child 7, script '/var/www/html/web/app_dev.php' (request: "GET /app_dev.php") executing too slow (2.226379 sec), logging
[09-Aug-2017 05:05:51] NOTICE: child 7 stopped for tracing
[09-Aug-2017 05:05:51] NOTICE: about to trace 7
[09-Aug-2017 05:05:51] ERROR: failed to open /proc/7/mem: Permission denied (13)
[09-Aug-2017 05:05:51] NOTICE: finished trace of 7
[09-Aug-2017 05:10:41] WARNING: [pool www] child 9, script '/var/www/html/web/app_dev.php' (request: "GET /app_dev.php") executing too slow (2.247990 sec), logging
[09-Aug-2017 05:10:41] NOTICE: child 9 stopped for tracing
[09-Aug-2017 05:10:41] NOTICE: about to trace 9
[09-Aug-2017 05:10:41] ERROR: failed to open /proc/9/mem: Permission denied (13)
[09-Aug-2017 05:10:41] NOTICE: finished trace of 9
[09-Aug-2017 05:12:41] WARNING: [pool www] child 11, script '/var/www/html/web/app_dev.php' (request: "GET /app_dev.php") executing too slow (2.494645 sec), logging
[09-Aug-2017 05:12:41] NOTICE: child 11 stopped for tracing
[09-Aug-2017 05:12:41] NOTICE: about to trace 11
[09-Aug-2017 05:12:41] ERROR: failed to open /proc/11/mem: Permission denied (13)
[09-Aug-2017 05:12:41] NOTICE: finished trace of 11
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Run `docker stats` in one terminal windows while making the failing request and see if there is any memory shoot?

Comment: Yes, there is. 100% memory use and 100% cpu

Comment: That's your problem. Give higher memory limit to your FPM container

Comment: Also, make sure that in your php-fpm config `max_execution_time` is not set to a low value like 160 seconds...